# Use public maven repository with ivy

Tags: maven-2, artifactory, ivy

I have an `ivy.xml` containing

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency org="commons-lang" name="commons-lang" rev="2.4"/>
  <dependency org="foo-bar" name="superwidgets" rev="1.5"/>
</dependencies>
```

The whole superwidget stuff is hosted in a maven repository at http://example.com/m2/.  The ivy documentation [mentions resolvers](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/resolver/url.html), but it seems to assume an ivy repository.  How can I add a single unofficial maven repository to my ivy settings to be used only by a single module?  (Or put another way, what corresponds to maven's `<repository>` tag in ivy?) Nothing fancy, so I'd expect a one-liner in my ivy.xml.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You need to add an **ivysettings.xml** file with the following repositories listed ([resolvers](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/resolvers.html) in ivy speak)

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="chain"/>
    <resolvers>
        <chain name="chain">
            <ibiblio name="central" m2compatible="true"/>
            <ibiblio name="example" m2compatible="true" root="http://example.com/m2/"/>
        </chain>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

In my opinion it makes more sense to separate the dependency declaration (ivy.xml) from the mechanism of retrieval (settings.xml). This is not needed in Maven because it only supports one type of repository.

If you want to get really fancy you can control which respository serves up a particular module:

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="central"/>
    <resolvers>
        <ibiblio name="central" m2compatible="true"/>
        <ibiblio name="example" m2compatible="true" root="http://example.com/m2/"/>
    </resolvers>
    <modules>
        <module organisation="foo-bar" name="superwidgets" resolver="example"/>
    </modules>
</ivysettings>
```

Comment: I'm new to this, tried with `<ibiblio name="tmatesoft-releases" m2compatible="true" root="http://maven.tmatesoft.com/content/repositories/releases/"/>` and got `unknown resolver main` and `unknown resolver public`

Answer (score 7):

I prefer chained resolvers that include SpringSource's EBR and Maven Central too, like this:

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="spring-chain" />
    <resolvers>
        <chain name="spring-chain">
            <url name="com.springsource.repository.bundles.release">
                <ivy pattern="http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/release/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
                <artifact pattern="http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/release/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
            </url>
            <url name="com.springsource.repository.bundles.external">
                <ivy pattern="http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/external/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
                <artifact pattern="http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/external/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
            </url>
            <ibiblio name="ibiblio" m2compatible="true"/>
        </chain>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

Although I do not use them directly, I prefer to [create and control my own local Ivy repository](http://www.drillio.com/en/software-build/apache-ivy/create-local-repository-guide/).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that tries to keep Ivy's default behavior and just add on repository, the `maven.tmatesoft.com` repo

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="default"/>

    <!-- These "magic lines" are pulled from: https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/tutorial/defaultconf.html -->
    <include url="${ivy.default.settings.dir}/ivysettings-public.xml"/>
    <include url="${ivy.default.settings.dir}/ivysettings-shared.xml"/>
    <include url="${ivy.default.settings.dir}/ivysettings-local.xml"/>
    <include url="${ivy.default.settings.dir}/ivysettings-main-chain.xml"/>
    <include url="${ivy.default.settings.dir}/ivysettings-default-chain.xml"/>
    <resolvers>
        <!-- Custom Repos here -->
        <ibiblio name="tmatesoft" m2compatible="true" root="https://maven.tmatesoft.com/content/repositories/releases/"/>
        <!--<filesystem name="internal">-->
            <!--<ivy pattern="${repository.dir}/[module]/ivy-[revision].xml"/>-->
            <!--<artifact pattern="${repository.dir}/[module]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>-->
        <!--</filesystem>-->
    </resolvers>
    <chain name="default" returnFirst="true" checkmodified="true" changingPattern=".*SNAPSHOT">
        <!-- These two are magic lines from the default conf -->
        <resolver ref="local"/>
        <resolver ref="main" />

        <!-- Custom Repos here -->
        <resolver ref="tmatesoft" />
    </chain>
    <modules>
        <module organisation="org.tmatesoft.hg4j" name=".*" resolver="tmatesoft"/>
    </modules>
</ivysettings>
```