# Play Framework: add Maven local repository

Tags: java, maven, playframework

In `Play`'s `dependencies.yml` configuration file, how can I add my local Maven repository (M2_HOME) to `repositories:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Play 1.x uses [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy) to resolve the dependencies. So you need to configure your [`ivysettings.xml`](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.2.0/tutorial/defaultconf.html) file to add any kind of Maven repository (including your local one).

You can see how to do that in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836011/use-public-maven-repository-with-ivy).