# Get latest google drive api by Ivy

Tags: maven, google-drive-api, ivy, google-api-java-client

I have add resolver to ivysettings.xml

```
  <ibiblio name="google-api-services" root="http://mavenrepo.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg" m2compatible="true" />
```

But get a error

```
 module not found: com.google.apis#google-api-services-drive;v2-rev13-1.8.0-beta
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It resolves fine for me..... Perhaps there is a problem with your ivysettings file?

The following example configures the google api services repo and Maven Central.

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="repos" />
    <resolvers>
        <chain name="repos">
            <ibiblio name="central" m2compatible="true"/>   
            <ibiblio name="google-api-services" m2compatible="true" root="http://mavenrepo.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg"/>
        </chain>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

Comment: Yes, I override default settings but forgot include share resolver

Comment: @atu0830 See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836011/use-public-maven-repository-with-ivy/4837149#4837149