# How to download an artifact with its dependencies to a specified directory - without pom.xml - using Maven?

Tags: java, maven

What I need to do is to download an artifact from my internal repository (currently [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/)) with all its dependencies, to a specified directory. And that without actually downloading the source code (and using its `pom.xml`): I need to just run a plain maven command from the shell and access the binaries in my repository.

I don't need to download the dependencies to my local repository (the behaviour of the [dependency:get](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html) / [dependency:copy](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html) plugins), I want the artifact AND all of its dependencies copied to a specified directory.

Something like this:

```
mvn super-downloader:download-everything -Dartifact=my.group:myArtifact:version -Ddirectory=.
```

What I've tried:

[dependency:get](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html) and [dependency:copy](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html) plugins copy the dependencies to my local repository (under ~/.m2) which is not what I want.

[dependency:copy-dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) requires a maven project. I need to run the command without a pom.xml.

[com.googlecode.maven-download-plugin:maven-download-plugin:artifact](https://github.com/maven-download-plugin/maven-download-plugin) plugin should work with `-DdependencyDepth=<some high value>`, but it fails trying to resolve a dependency to `xerces:xerces-impl:2.6.2`. I manually uploaded it to my Nexus, but then it failed trying to find `xml-apis:xml-apis:2.6.2`, which doesn't exist.

So, any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450383/using-maven-to-download-dependencies-to-a-directory-on-the-command-line/15456621#15456621

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspired by the [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15484858/1013327), I created a simple bash script to solve the problem:

```
#mvn-copy.sh
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:copy -Dmdep.useBaseVersion=true -DoutputDirectory=. -Dartifact=$1:$2:$3
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:copy -Dmdep.stripVersion=true  -DoutputDirectory=. -Dartifact=$1:$2:$3:pom
mvn -f $2.pom org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=lib
```

To use it, just type `./mvn-copy.sh <groupId> <artifactId> <version>`. It will download the main jar at the current directory, and then all dependencies into a `lib` folder.

Not the best solution, not the most beautiful one, and not quite what I wanted, but it solved the problem and saved the day.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MDEP-322 which seems a fair request