# Using Vaadin on NetBeans WITHOUT Maven

Tags: java, netbeans, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm starting with Vaadin and I'd like to know if it's possible work with this framework in NetBeans without using maven. The reason is the project using maven takes ages downloading dependencies and never reaches to run because of a timeout connection problem.

I've downloaded the [All-in-one file](https://vaadin.com/downloading?package=release/7.1/7.1.11/vaadin-all-7.1.11.zip) and tried following these README.txt file instructions:

> 1. Copy all vaadin-* files except vaadin-client and vaadin-client-compiler to WEB-INF/lib in your project
> 2. Copy lib/*.jar to WEB-INF/lib in your project
> 3. Copy vaadin-client and vaadin-client-compiler to a lib folder which is on your classpath but will not be deployed. These files are only
>      needed when compiling a module (widget set) to Javascript.

But had no luck compiling the widgetset.

I was looking for a couple of days but I can't find a way to make it work. I've read the [Book of Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/getting-started.netbeans.html) section about NetBeans and I've searched in Google with no positive result.

I know questions asking for tutorials or libraries are off-topic in this site but I really don't know how sort this issue. Any hint will be appreaciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We initially also wished to do netbeans development with vaadin 7, without having to use the maven stuff.

In Vaadin6 this was simple, it worked fine.
But for Vaadin 7 we have not been able to do it in a reasonable way.
So we finally switched to maven for the Vaadin7 projects.

You can install a nexus repository which caches the maven downloads, so it can prevent the timeout problems.

Not sure what the Vaadin Plugin actually allows you to do, but perhaps this one also works without maven?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've seen a way to work without maven on Vaadin 6 too but the same doesn't work on 7. I'll take a look to nexus as well.

Comment: I have cut to the chase, have installed Eclipse and it worked. Still prefer NetBeans but I can live with that. Thanks for your time and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a dependency issue, you can use Maven to download all jars to a directory and then add the jars to a netbeans project. e.g. [Using Maven to download dependencies to a directory on the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450383/using-maven-to-download-dependencies-to-a-directory-on-the-command-line)

Comment: Hi there! +1 and thank you for the response. I'll try it too. But in theory downloading the `all-in-one` zip file and following the instructions it should work (same as downloading dependencies from maven repository). I did it and have no problem with dependencies but cannot compile the widgetset which is needed to run the application. I will try if these steps work with Eclipse.