# Vaadin on Netbeans -- which jar?

Tags: netbeans, vaadin, vaadin7, netbeans-8

i'm looking to use Vaadin on Netbeans 8.

I installed the Vaadin plug-in on Netbeans.

Followed the instructions on https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Getting+Started+on+NetBeans.

The jar i'm using is [vaadin-all-7.3.8](https://vaadin.com/downloading?package=release/7.3/7.3.7/vaadin-all-7.3.8.zip).

I assigned Tomcat to the project.

However - `com.vaadin` isn't recognized for all what it has in the environment-- `com.vaadin.ui` and `com.vaadin.Application` aren't seen. 
I'm getting checked errors to

```
import com.vaadin.Application;
```

and

```
import com.vaadin.ui.*;
```

, but not to

```
import com.vaadin.*;
```

What more do i need for Vaadin on Netbeans??

TIA.

//=======================

EDIT:

Pls note: Saw [Using Vaadin on NetBeans WITHOUT Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22305315/using-vaadin-on-netbeans-without-maven) along with some other discussions.

Also note: We're looking to avoid Vaadin-on-Maven. have already had issues with that one as well.

Comment: For vaadin 6.x we did use it with normal Netbeans java web projects. Worked fine. When we did then switch to vaadin 7, we did try to stay way from maven and ivy, but finally we did not suceed and are now using maven for our vaadin 7.x projects...

Comment: The Wiki entry you quoted is only for vaadin 6.x, won't help with vaadin 7

Comment: do you know of any help/resource to show these step by step? getting dizzy finding my way around in Vaadin "help" resources

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to read the readme in the zip file that tells you which jar files you need to include in your project:

1. Copy all vaadin-* files except vaadin-client and vaadin-client-compiler to WEB-INF/lib in your project
2. Copy lib/*.jar to WEB-INF/lib in your project
3. Copy vaadin-client and vaadin-client-compiler to a lib folder which is on your classpath but will not be deployed. These files are only needed when compiling a module (widget set) to Javascript.

What issues did you have with maven? Typically I would recommend using a dependency management tool to make upgrades easier in the future.

Comment: what issues i'm having are in the Q. also stopped now seeing any of com.vaadin that i removed Vaadin6 from the prj jar/libs.  
WE"RE AVOIDING MAVEN ON PRJ.