# Retrieve deployable artifacts from maven hosted repository via a tool

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to automate some of our processes at work.
I would like give operations a file that just listed war files that needed deployed, then have a script download those war files from our maven repository.  The script will deploy them but the "act" of downloading them is what I'd like to piggy back off of.

I do realize that I could have a script transpose names/groupid/artifactid/versions into wget or http downloads, have maven download them with a pom file, or use groovy grape.
However, I would imagine that getting maven artifacts outside of the maven lifecycle is something that is done often and that someone has already written something to do this.

I just want them downloaded to a central folder where the wrapping script can call jboss-cli can deploy them.
something like this:

```
deployFile.eachLine{
  **WANTEDTOOL**.download(it)
  /opt/jboss/bin/jboss-cli --connect deploy /opt/lib/...
}
```

I'd much prefer to use a tool in this case rather than invent something i need to maintain.

Thanks

Comment: Why **isn't** this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908090/downloading-all-maven-dependencies-to-a-directory-not-in-repository ?

Comment: @DanielKaplan:  I'm not convinced that it's a duplicate either, since a deploy may mean that the machine building the artifacts doesn't deploy them at all.  Merely copying them from one location on the local machine to the other doesn't quite satisfy.

Comment: we are trying to achieve two different end goals through similar activities, the suggestion of using ivy from the command line is what I am looking for.  I also looked at my title and its horrible.

Comment: I found this and it worked for me:

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450383/using-maven-to-download-dependencies-to-a-directory-on-the-command-line