# Is there a way to download dependencies from a pom.xml in an automated manor without maven installed?

Tags: java, maven

Is there any method, which allows me to download the maven dependencies using a pom.xml, without having maven installed?

Note the use of another computer is not possible, nor is using another build tool, or installing one.

I would appreciate answers not breaking these constraints, as that already has answers: [Using Maven to download dependencies to a directory on the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450383/using-maven-to-download-dependencies-to-a-directory-on-the-command-line).

Comment: Well, I guess those restrictions are there for a reason. Can't you have your Softworkers do that stuff for you? If you need that for your work, then there has got to be a way to come to the results without you being fired.

Comment: I'm sure they have their reasons. Doesn't help my situation. I don't have any Softworkers ) :

Comment: I was talking about the Software-Dept. If this "I want to run a few maven projects off github " isn't personal fun but serious work to get your actual job done, then I am sure you will be given the possibility to come to the results of that research. Either by giving you the needed rights and software or by delegating it to a person that has the rights and software. If your boss will decline any stuff from github anyway, then running some project off it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm just an intern, I can't get the rights, I only want a template, not going to use the code.

Comment: Then the only answer must be: This is impossible without breaking at least one of your constraints.

Comment: @Fildor I would rather have that as an answer than an answer which is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of such a tool.

You can use the [maven-dependency-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) and inject the following snippet in your `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
        <phase>process-resources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/target/libs</outputDirectory>
          <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
          <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
          <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Then, take this pom and run maven:

```
mvn clean process-resources
```

Run it *outside* your problematic network.
All dependencies will be resolved and copied to `${project.build.directory}/target/libs`

I hope this helps.

Comment: I can't use maven on my computer.

Comment: @Snickers3192 Eldad tried to tell you to run this not at work, but somewhere else.

Comment: And I tried to tell him I need to do it on my work computer.

Comment: @Snickers3192, find a computer running Java and Maven outside your company. @ Home, @ a friend's house. Run it there and collect all your dependencies.