# Accessing remote Maven repo through Ant

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, ant, gradle

Is there a way to access a remote Maven repo through the Ant build system?

*The remote Maven repo is built for the purpose of being accessed with the Android Studio Gradle build system but some old projects want to access the repo using Ant build system.*

Comment: Probably yes, via Ivy.

Comment: Ivy can be configured to download dependencies from any Maven repository. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836011/use-public-maven-repository-with-ivy/4837149#4837149

Comment: And a working ivy example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15979391/class-not-found-with-ant-ivy-and-junit-error-in-build-xml/15982144#15982144