# Best practice for storing dependencies when automating builds for java applications

Tags: ant, jenkins, amazon-s3, build-automation, build-dependencies

We are looking into adopting a more CI friendly approach to managing our on premise jar dependency file server or doing away with it entirely for a better alternative. Right now it is just a Linux server with some form of file structure for example:

```
http://server_name/vault/apache.org/axis/version_number/axis.jar
http://server_name/vault/apache.org/axis/version_number/jaxrpc.jar
http://server_name/vault/apache.org/axis/version_number/axis.jar
```

Was wondering what type of standard adopted enterprise CI practices for managing these dependencies when you are doing automated builds.

- Would storing them in AWS S3 be a good idea?
- Are there any applications that help manage the jar dependency library? (Looking for open source solutions preferably). For example something similar to where you simply add a jar you need, and pull it down using an API when doing a build.
- Assuming that apache ant is used for building out the project. And if that doesn't play well in the CI realm, what would be a good alternative?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [Apache ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) to manage your build's dependencies. Ivy can be configured to pull your dependencies from Maven repositories which is pretty much the defacto standard now for storing Java binaries.

- [Use public maven repository with ivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836011/use-public-maven-repository-with-ivy/4837149#4837149)

[Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/) is the largest repository of Java binaries. To host your private binaries there are various ready made options: [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/), [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/open-source/) or [Archiva](http://archiva.apache.org/index.cgi)

Comment: Is there a way to host a local maven repository?

Comment: @alexfvolk Yes. Nexus, Artifactory or Archiva