# can we use separate resolver for downloading dependency jar in ivy ANT?

Tags: ant, jar, ivy, nexus

I am using IVY ANT task for publishing jar file into nexus repository.
before publishing using some dependency jars for ant build compilation.
So first step is to publish jar into nexus repository, that I can do using resolver from ivy.xml file.
Now in second step I want to download the jar file from another repository , so can I provide different resolver in dependency tag in ivy.xml

Answer (score 0):

I don't entirely understand what you're trying to do, but you can structure your ivy settings file to pull a particular dependency from an alternative repository.

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="repo1"/>
    <resolvers>
        <ibiblio name="repo1" m2compatible="true" root="http://example1.com/repo/"/>
        <ibiblio name="repo2" m2compatible="true" root="http://example2.com/repo/"/>
    </resolvers>
    <modules>
        <module organisation="my-special-org" name="my-app" resolver="repo2"/>
    </modules>
</ivysettings>
```

By default **repo1** is used, but the "my-app" artifact is downloaded from **repo2**

See also the following answer

- [Use public maven repository with ivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836011/use-public-maven-repository-with-ivy/4837149#4837149)

Comment: Ohh I didn't find this root attribute. Will try this one. Thanks dude.