# Using a Maven Feed (package Management) in VSTS as a ivy resolver

Tags: java, ant, continuous-integration, ivy

I was reading up on package management in VSTS to manage local dependencies in my Java project via a Maven feed in VSTS. One concept which I have not tried out yet is creating a Maven Feed housing my local dependencies and using a ivy resolver (either ibiblio or url) for resolving my dependencies pointing to the Maven Feed URL. I need to use ivy resolvers since my project is build via apache ant and ivy during build in VSTS (build would be taken care in Jenkins). Since checking in the local binaries into a folder into my source code and using a ivy file resolver is not something that I can do, so was wondering whether the above mentioned option is doable or not. Any pointers would be really helpful.

Comment: These threads may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836011/use-public-maven-repository-with-ivy and http://www.draconianoverlord.com/2010/07/18/publishing-to-maven-repos-with-ivy.html

Comment: Thank you for the response. The threads that you posted mention how to connect to a local maven repository. My question is more towards whether a Maven Feed created in VSTS can be used as a normal maven repository to refer from a ivy resolver or are there other steps that need to be taken into consideration.