# Change the order of Maven repos with spark.jars.ivySettings

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc

According to the doc of `spark.jars.packages` [1](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html), Spark dependencies are first searched in local and Maven Central then custom repos from `spark.jars.repositories`:

> Comma-separated list of Maven coordinates of jars to include on the driver and executor classpaths. The coordinates should be groupId:artifactId:version. If spark.jars.ivySettings is given artifacts will be resolved according to the configuration in the file, otherwise artifacts will be searched for in the local maven repo, then maven central and finally any additional remote repositories given by the command-line option --repositories.

I wanted to change the order (custom repo first) with `spark.jars.ivySettings`, but don't know the exact syntax of the file. A simple example would help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of configuring GCS Maven Mirror before Maven Central:

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="chain"/>
    <resolvers>
    <chain name="chain">
            <ibiblio name="gcs" m2compatible="true" root="https://maven-central.storage-download.googleapis.com/maven2/" />
            <ibiblio name="central" m2compatible="true" root="https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/" />
        </chain>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

I found this thread helpful: [Use public maven repository with ivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836011/use-public-maven-repository-with-ivy).